# Installing sqlite3 on ubuntu without sudo apt-get install

Tags: linux, sqlite, ubuntu

So I'm going to preface this by saying that I CANNOT use `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`. I am doing this project in a VM on google cloud platform, and our VMs are not allowed to have external IP access because we have sensitive information on these VMs. So running that command just hangs.

I went to the [sqlite website](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and downloaded the Precompiled Binaries for Linux and put that on google cloud storage (gcs). I am able to `cp` the directory from gcs to the VM, but 
ultimately, I cannot figure out a way to get it to run. When I `cd` to the directory, I see there are 3 objects `sqldiff`, `sqlite3`, `sqlite3_analyzer`, of which Im including an image in case you want to reference it.

[image: shell]

I was testing out an idea at home, where I have  a pc that can dual boot linux, and I was able to run sqlite3 just find from the command when I did a `sudo apt-get` for it (i.e. I get

```
SQLite version 3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
```

), but I'm having problems here. I can't seem to do anything after this within the VM I am trying to run the actual code in now. I am pretty inexperienced with ubuntu and linux systems, so maybe I'm just missing something easy.

Thank you to anyone who can offer some advice.

Comment: you can just `cp` the binary files to your local bin directory and you will be able to use sqlite in your system. `sudo cp BINARY_FILES /usr/local/bin` or add the directory to your system path: `export PATH="BINARY_FILES_DIR:$PATH"` where BINARY_FILES_DIR is the binary files location or directory, by doing this you can use the binaries system wide from anywhere you can execute sqlite command.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried building the binaries from source?
https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html

This worked for me when I downloaded the source code amalgamation.

Ideally, `gcc` should be present on your VM

```
$ : gcc shell.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl -o sqlite3_cli                                                                                                
$ : ./sqlite3_cli                                                                                                                                       
SQLite version 3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>
```